# php sorting sql records

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops

I'm looping through records in a table, and in each loop it opens another table to pull data from it. I need to ORDER the main loop ($rs) by a field from the 2nd table.

I'm somewhat a beginner to php and sql so go easy on me :P

code example:

```
$sql_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1", $db); // i want this to ORDER BY data from table2
while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result)) { 
    $sql_result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id='$rs[data]'", $db); 
    $rs2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result2);

    //get data from table 2
```

Comment: we need more information, specially regading the tables and what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping through a resultset and executing a second query for each row is bad practice and causes unnecessary load on the database.
It looks like you need an `INNER JOIN`:

```sql
    SELECT t1.*
      FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.data
  ORDER BY t2.field
```

This way, you can get all the data with **one** single query.

---

*EDIT:*
Generally you should try to avoid returning all columns (`SELECT *`) and select only the columns that you really need:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.field1, t1.field2, ...
```

This will not only reduce the load on the database (less data to select and to transfer over the network), but it will also help to eliminate double column names because double column names cause problems when you want to display them (as you found out yourself).

You can do two things to avoid this problem:

1. if both tables have columns with identical names and identical content (e.g. if these columns are used to join the tables), just select one of them (no matter which one, because they are identical).
2. if both tables have columns with identical names and different content and you need both of them, the easiest way would be to give one of them an alias:

   ```
   SELECT t1.id, t2.id AS AnotherId, ...
   ```

   This will cause the second column to be named "AnotherId", so you can get it with  `$rs[AnotherId]`.
   Honestly, I'm no PHP guru so I don't know if PHP understands `$rs[table.field]` as well, but there are enough data access technologies which have problems when a query returns two columns with identical names...so aliasing duplicate columns can never be wrong.

Comment: thank you. and how would i call the fields for an echo statement, i usually use $rs[field], would it be the same or would I have to do $rs[table.field] ?

Comment: Column names don't automatically change when they're returned in a result set, so you should be able to continue referring to them by name. Grabbing every column via SELECT * is inefficient unless your application actually requires every column in the result set, so you'd be better off specifying exactly which columns you want from t1 and t2, which will also give you the ability to rename/relabel any columns that have the same name in both tables.

Comment: The `t1` stuff is just an alias for the table name, exactly like the alias for the columns that I just edited into my answer. When you have to write the table name multiple times (like when you join several tables), it's easier to write `t1.field` instead of `LongTableName.field`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you've been a huge help

Comment: @user880356: to express your gratitude even more, you could also upvote my answer ;-)  (I see in your profile that you never voted at all yet)

Comment: It says I need more rep :o

Can you join say.. 3 tables using INNER JOIN too?

Comment: You're right, I forgot that you need 15 rep to upvote. Yes, you can join more than two tables, the syntax is basically the same. Just search for "join three tables mysql" here at SO if you want to see some examples.